# phantomjs rasterize has problems with url parameters

Tags: phantomjs, url-parameters

I'm on a windows machine using the standard commandline tool and using `PhantomJS` and a modified `rasterize.js` code.  The problem I have is when I pass the url, `http://time.com/3274245/e-cigarettes-debate/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+time/topstories+(TIME:+Top+Stories)`.  I've redirected the `StandardOutput` and the `StandardError` and here's what I get with the above url.

StandardOutput

```
Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]
  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"
```

StandardErrror

```
'utm_source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'utm_medium' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'utm_campaign' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So the question is, Is there any way resolve the problem with the parameters in the url?

Please let me know if there is any information that is missing or if anything needs to be clarified.

I'll add my modified `rasterize.js` below.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size;

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1200, height: 1200 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                           : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 10000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What OS/shell are you on? Different shells need different quoting of parameters.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm on a windows machine using the standard command line tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In windows cmd you need to use quotes around parameters that might have special characters. A `=` is a good candidate for when something breaks.

```
phantomjs rasterize.js "http://time.com/..." time.png
```

For this page specifically you might need to disable web security:

```
phantomjs --web-security=false rasterize.js "http://time.com/..." time.png
```

Comment: Thanks!  This got me past the parameters issue.  I now see I have another issue to resolve, but hey, one more step towards perfection! :)